# How to Make a Simple POST Request Using Jersey (JAX-RS) to NTLM Authenticated Server

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs, ntlm

I have looked online and have found articles like:

[NonRepeatableRequestException using jersey and apache httpClient for a REST call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42064425/nonrepeatablerequestexception-using-jersey-and-apache-httpclient-for-a-rest-call?rq=1&newreg=6397941a3037420eb17467bc85f52956)

and:

[How to send NTLM authenticated post request using jersey?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30075951/how-to-send-ntlm-authenticated-post-request-using-jersey)

The answer for the second only provides a solution for GET requests. I am setting up my Client as follows:

```
private void init() {
    if (client == null) {
        client = ClientBuilder.newClient(prepareClientConfig());
    }
}

private ClientConfig prepareClientConfig() {
    ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
    CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new NTCredentials(userId, password, null, null));
    config.property(ApacheClientProperties.CREDENTIALS_PROVIDER, credentialsProvider);
    config.connectorProvider(new ApacheConnectorProvider());
    return config;
}
```

Here is where I make a GET request:

```
@Override
public Response get(String uri, List<HttpUrlParameter> params) throws WebCallException {
    init();
    String url = baseUrl + restUri + apiVersion + uri;
    WebTarget webTarget = client.target(url);
    for (HttpUrlParameter param : params) {
        webTarget = webTarget.queryParam(param.getKey(), param.getValue());
    }
    Response response = webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get();
    return response;
}
```

The HttpUrlParameter and WebCallException classes are defined by me. The GET request above works great. Then I attempt the POST call:

```
@Override
public Response post(String uri, Object entity, List<HttpUrlParameter> params) throws WebCallException {
    init();
    String url = baseUrl + restUri + apiVersion + uri;
    WebTarget webTarget = client.target(url);
    for (HttpUrlParameter param : params) {
        webTarget = webTarget.queryParam(param.getKey(), param.getValue());
    }
    Response response = webTarget
              .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
              .post(Entity.json(entity));
    return response;
}
```

The Entity that I am passing in for this particular test is pretty straight-forward:

```
import java.util.Date;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class CrmAccount {

    @JsonProperty("accountid")
    private String accountId;
    @JsonProperty("accountnumber")
    private String accountNumber;
    private String name;
    @JsonProperty("emailaddress1")
    private String emailAddress1;
    @JsonProperty("telephone1")
    private String phoneNumber;
    @JsonProperty("address1_addressid")
    private String address1Id;
    @JsonProperty("address1_line1")
    private String address1Line1;
    @JsonProperty("address1_line2")
    private String address1Line2;
    @JsonProperty("address1_city")
    private String address1City;
    @JsonProperty("address1_stateorprovince")
    private String address1StateOrProvince;
    @JsonProperty("address1_postalcode")
    private String address1PostalCode;
    @JsonProperty("address1_county")
    private String address1Country;

    public CrmAccount() {
        super();
    }

    public String getAccountId() {
        return accountId;
    }

    public void setAccountId(String accountId) {
        this.accountId = accountId;
    }

    public String getAccountNumber() {
        return accountNumber;
    }

    public void setAccountNumber(String accountNumber) {
        this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmailAddress1() {
        return emailAddress1;
    }

    public void setEmailAddress1(String emailAddress1) {
        this.emailAddress1 = emailAddress1;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public String getAddress1Id() {
        return address1Id;
    }

    public void setAddress1Id(String address1Id) {
        this.address1Id = address1Id;
    }

    public String getAddress1Line1() {
        return address1Line1;
    }

    public void setAddress1Line1(String address1Line1) {
        this.address1Line1 = address1Line1;
    }

    public String getAddress1Line2() {
        return address1Line2;
    }

    public void setAddress1Line2(String address1Line2) {
        this.address1Line2 = address1Line2;
    }

    public String getAddress1City() {
        return address1City;
    }

    public void setAddress1City(String address1City) {
        this.address1City = address1City;
    }

    public String getAddress1StateOrProvince() {
        return address1StateOrProvince;
    }

    public void setAddress1StateOrProvince(String address1StateOrProvince) {
        this.address1StateOrProvince = address1StateOrProvince;
    }

    public String getAddress1PostalCode() {
        return address1PostalCode;
    }

    public void setAddress1PostalCode(String address1PostalCode) {
        this.address1PostalCode = address1PostalCode;
    }

    public String getAddress1Country() {
        return address1Country;
    }

    public void setAddress1Country(String address1Country) {
        this.address1Country = address1Country;
    }
}
```

I am able to make the POST call via Postman without any issue, so I know that the call (outside of my Java code) works fine. When I make the POST call using Jersey, I get the following exception:

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
        at org.glassfish.jersey.apache.connector.ApacheConnector.apply(ApacheConnector.java:481)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:252)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:684)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:681)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:444)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:681)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:437)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.post(JerseyInvocation.java:343)
        at com.harpercollinschristian.integration.util.rest.crm.RestApiClientCrmImpl.post(RestApiClientCrmImpl.java:119)
        at com.harpercollinschristian.integration.service.crm.CrmRestfulApi$4.request(CrmRestfulApi.java:127)
        at com.harpercollinschristian.integration.util.rest.crm.CrmRestApiRequest.exec(CrmRestApiRequest.java:53)
        at com.harpercollinschristian.integration.service.crm.CrmRestfulApi.createAccount(CrmRestfulApi.java:132)
        at com.harpercollinschristian.integration.service.crm.CrmRestfulApiTest.testCreateAccount(CrmRestfulApiTest.java:80)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:254)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:186)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:71)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.apache.connector.ApacheConnector.apply(ApacheConnector.java:435)
        ... 44 more
Caused by: org.apache.http.client.NonRepeatableRequestException: Cannot retry request with a non-repeatable request entity.
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:225)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
        ... 46 more
```

It seems to me that the JSON Entity being passed to the post() method is possibly setup as a stream that can only be called once? The JSON messages that I need to send for all my POST and PATCH calls are not long and can easily be represented as a String using the FasterXML / Jackson library - so we should be easily able to "repeat" the entity. I know that there is something probably pretty obvious that I am missing, but I cannot find a solution. The project is using Jersey Client for REST API calls to two other non-Microsoft (and therefore non-NTLM) services, so I need to use Jersey for those (in otherwords I do not want to pull Jersey out if I can help it).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I received a code snippet from our partner with Microsoft CRM that had the answer. Our method that sets up the configuration needed to be updated to:

```
private ClientConfig prepareClientConfig() {
    ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
    CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    final AuthScope ntlmAuthScope = new AuthScope(null, -1, AuthScope.ANY_REALM, "NTLM");
    credentialsProvider.setCredentials(ntlmAuthScope, new NTCredentials(userId, password, null, null));
    config.property(ApacheClientProperties.CREDENTIALS_PROVIDER, credentialsProvider);
    config.property(ClientProperties.REQUEST_ENTITY_PROCESSING, RequestEntityProcessing.BUFFERED);
    config.connectorProvider(new ApacheConnectorProvider());
    return config;
}
```

Note the config property for REQUEST_ENTITY_PROCESSING - set to BUFFERED. That, I believe, was what we needed to allow the entity to be buffered and therefore reused for the subsequent requests (to satisfy the NTLM protocol). There are a couple of other additions as well (e.g. specific AuthScope).